# How to modify object size in python

Tags: python, garbage-collection

We have a following piece of code:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")

class Buf(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.__addr = libc.malloc(size)

    def __del__(self):
        libc.free(self.__addr)
```

The production code is more complicated, the thing is that there is some RAII-like object that allocates and frees memory using `libc`.

Is there any way to inform garbage collector about the full size of this object - the size it's already aware of + size of memory allocated with `libc`?

I'm aware that I can achieve similar allocation by using ctypes:

```
def createBuf(size):
    class Buf(ctypes.Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [("data", ctypes.c_ubyte*size)]

    return Buf()
```

but for some reason let's assume that using libc directly is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector does not need to know anything, just free every allocation in your `__del__` function.

```
class Buf(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.__addr = libc.malloc(size)
        self.pointers = {}

    def allocate(name, size, amount):
        self.pointers[name] = libc.calloc(amount, size)

    def get(name):
        return self.pointers[name]     

    def __del__(self):
        for pointer in self.pointers:
            libc.free(pointer)

        libc.free(self.__addr)
```

You could even make Buf a subclass of ctypes.c_void_p and free the Buf pointer with libc.free(self) if you also create it with

```
class Buf(ctypes.c_void_p):
    def __new__(cls, size):
        return malloc(size)

    ...

    def __del__(self):
        ... 

        libc.free(self)
```

Comment: I know that it will free my memory correctly anyway.

My concern was that it is not aware how big is my object.

I would like to help him with deciding when it is worth to do it, and which object should it free at first.

Comment: Then count the size in your Buf instance, something like a self.size += size or track the individual allocations in a dictionary if that is what you want.

Comment: That is not the solution either. I know what is the size of the object. The question is how to tell about it to GC.

Comment: Why do you want to know how large the data inside your Buf object is? Python works with reference counting, the GC does not care about the size of an object, it will only destroy it when the reference counter reaches 0.